# Feedback Widget?

Tags: animation, widget, feedback

I looked around before asking (used Google and this forum) so I wouldn't double post, (hopefully I'm not) but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Working on a project I was assigned to when I came across something I'd like to have present on my site.
It's a little animated '-/+' feedback widget which was found [[here](http://copyright.gov/title17/92chap3.html)] at the bottom right of the page.

How can I get something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular one seems to be a service of http://opinionlab.com but it looks to be something you pay for.

I would recommend something like http://uservoice.com or http://userrules.com which offer free accounts for small projects.

If you just want to recreate the spinning icon, it looks like they are just using an animated gif:

[image: spinning!] http://www.loc.gov/global/onlineopinionF3cS/en-US/black_oo.gif

Comment: Oh. Well thanks! Kudos to you.

Comment: Uservoice doesn't provide free plans for years now. Check out https://www.prodcamp.com for a feedback widget, they have a hidden free plan for startups.