# Feedback Widget with page questions

Tags: widget, survey, feedback, user-feedback

I'm looking for a feedback widget similar to get satisfaction that will allow me to purpose a few unique question per page. We are launching a website and want to ask a few questions on every page to our beta users and are looking for a feedback widget that has this capability built in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: did look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548781/feedback-widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548781/feedback-widget)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found a solution yet, but check out squidcube.com. Our embedded items are the exact solution you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try Feedback Lite - http://www.feedbacklite.com/tour/. You can customize your questions, layout, and also run multiple surveys across your site on different pages at the same time.

Comment: please provide relevant portion from the link.